# State the null and alternative hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Researchers at Griffin University conducted a study to determine whether video game players have superior visual attention skills compared to non-video game players. A sample of 30 male video game players had a mean score of 83.75 with a sample standard deviation of 9.56 on a visual attention test. A sample of 29 male non-video game players had a mean score of 87.14 with a sample standard deviation of 8.43 on the same test. Determine whether video game players have lower visual attention skills than non-video game players at a level of significance of 0.05

For the null I have meu= .05
        alternative meu <.05

Comment: .05 is actually the significance level in which you will compare the p-value to. It's not the value you're testing in the Null Hypothesis

Comment: I couldn't find what the null could be because the problem shows all different numbers.

Comment: I understand. See my comment, and let me know if you need help entering the data into the graphing calculator.

Comment: I believe it should be "fail to reject" the null hypothesis

Comment: I have that at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to perform a hypothesis test (t-test). This can be done using a graphing calculator which is most commonly used for beginning statistics students.

You'll be testing:

*Null: video game players and non-video game players have the same visual attention skills.*

$$\text{$\mu $1}=\text{$\mu $2}$$ 
*Alternative: video game players have lower visual attention skills than non-video game players.*
$$\text{$\mu $1}<\text{$\mu $2}$$

Since you have two (small) samples, I would perform a 2-SampleTtest in the graphing calculator. This can also be performed in other computer software's such as R.

The 2-SampleTtest requires a mean, standard deviation and sample size, all of which you have.

Depending on how you enter the data in the calculator, make sure the alternative hypothesis is that video game players < non video game players.

I got p-value .0768, thus at a 5% significance level, you **fail to reject** the null hypothesis and it appears that video game players and non video game players perform equally on visual attention skills.

Or you can say, there is insufficient evidence to conclude that video game players perform lower on visual attention skills than non video game players.